# Unable to set target .NET version in editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I seem to be having trouble setting the version of .NET used in the Visual Studio editor.

I have a class library that targets several versions of .NET. As you can see in the image below, I've selected .NET 7.0 as the active version. Yet code that is specific to .NET 7.0 and later is grayed out (at least, as indicated by `NET7_0_OR_GREATER`).

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to set the target framework to .NET 7.0 in the editor?

Comment: Those entries are from your `launchSettings.config` - they do not control the .NET version your project targets: that is controlled by the `<TargetFrameworks>` MSBuild property in your `.csproj`.

Comment: @Dai: As shown in the drop down, my `<TargetFrameworks>` tag contains `net7.0`, `net6.0`, `net5.0` and `netstandard2.0`. I'm asking how to specify which of those targets should be used by the editor.

Comment: Use the top-left drop-down in the Navigation Bar within the VS editor (in your screenshot it says _"Something.Helper (netstandard2.0)"_) - **not** the Start Project button's dropdown side-button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Dai's comments, the target I was setting controls what happens when I launch the application (which doesn't make much sense for a class library).

To control the target framework in the editor, use the left of the three drop downs at the top of the edit window.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT: This question was closed.

Comment: Case is closed and you can still mark the answer (at least I think your answer is very clear and helpful)